# Switch statement with array

Tags: c, arrays, switch-statement

I have run in to a bug in my code I cannot figure out. I am using an array and a switch statement together. a default is set for if user enters invalid selection, then the program loops back to ask for user input. Following the default selection the data entered by the user is not stored. This is only for the loop immediately after the default selection. Following is the main body of my code

//ask user to enter up to 20 numbers, find the average of the numbers and display average to user

```
main()
 {

    double number[SIZE] = { 0 };
    int i;
    int selection = 0, numCount = 0;
    double total = 0, average = 0;


    while(selection != 4){

    for (i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++)

    {

        printf("\nPress 1 to enter a number, you may enter up to 20\nPress 2 to display your numbers\nPress 3 to see the average of your numbers\nPress 4 to quit\n");
        scanf_s("%i", &selection);

        switch (selection) {
        case 1:

            if (numCount < SIZE) {
                //prompt user for input and store data
                printf("Please enter your number\n");
                scanf_s("%lf", &number[i]);
                numCount++;
                total += number[i];
            }
            else
                printf("\nThe array is full, choose another selection\n");
            break;

        case 2:

            if (numCount != 0)
        {
            //displays input back to user
            for (i = 0; i < numCount; i++)
                printf("%.2lf\t", number[i]);
        }
        else
            printf("You must input at least one number first\n");
            break;

        case 3:
            if (numCount != 0)

            {
                //calculates average of only numbers entered into the array by the user
                average = total / numCount;
                printf("The average of your numbers is %.2lf\n", average);
                break;
            }
            else
                printf("You must input at least one number first\n");

        case 4:
        {
            printf("Thank you\n\n");
            return;
        }
        default:
        {
            printf("This is not a valid selection, please try again\n\n");
            break;
        }

        } 

    }
}
}
```

Comment: And what's your question? Why do you need braces in case 4 and default? Where is break in case 3?

Comment: Two problems: (1) You are using `i` for two different loops (see the `case 2`) - this will cause all sorts of problem (change inner loop to a different index). (2) You are increasing `i` on every loop and using that as the index of your input number, even after a non-input selection.

Comment: Thanks so much! A five second fix.